# Debug or trace java application in linux console on remote server

Tags: java, linux, debugging, console

I have java app which I didn't write (actually, I'm not good at java at all). I don't have sources for it, just a ready-to-use binary. I'm experiencing weird issues with it which have no sense at all, in certain environments. I have strong suspicion that it's simply a configuration issue, but without proper documentation and anybody to ask, I had to resort to try-and-error approach in attempt to find out what else it needs, which didn't succeed.

My last hope is to somehow get more runtime debug/log info from it, but unfortunately it doesn't have logging functionality.

I've checked similar questions here, and though they propose a way to debug java app, it implies you have sources in some kind IDE, like Eclipse, connect to it remotely etc. Too much overhead for a layman like me, I have zero experience with Eclipse, too, and no sources, remember.

So I hoped may be there is still some tool that can "hack into" running java app and print some usefull information of what actually it doing. Something similar to what strace tool does for regular exe files.

Anything like that for java?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are certain profiling tools out there; that also support instrumentation. Using such tools you could create a full trace of all method calls and so on.

But without source code, that will not help you. Thus, I think you need **two** things:

1. You need to acquire source code (for example by running the class files through a Java [decompiler](http://www.javadecompilers.com/))
2. Then you need to study the sources. Of course that means: you have to study java, too.

If "1." doesn't work out ... you are at a dead. You see, you just assume that you are dealing with configuration issues, but in essence: a lot of things are possible. How would you fix **bugs** if you don't have source code to work with?!

If "2." is beyond the things you want/can do; then you are at a dead end, too.

Long story short: there are no miracles around. You can't debug an application that you don't have "access" to. So you better think twice; and spent some time on thinking up "plan B" (how to get out of this situation without loosing face/job/reputation/...). So far, what you are telling us sounds like a situation were chances are high for you to fail. So better be prepared for that.

Comment: Thanks for your input, GhostCat. The good thing is that I don't need to debug it, what I need is to get a general understanding of steps it performs during execution, like which files it opens, which functions it calls with what results, etc. I've used strace before when it was about exe files, and it was often very helpful. I'm almost sure it's not a bug, but some requirements that are hardcoded into it. So some hint like attempt to open file or call function on one system, which fails at another could give me enough insight of how to fix it.